# Laravel Eloquent ORM firstOrNew mass assignment exception

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to look up a model in my database based on 2 fields, and if it doesn't exist, create a new model which contains those two values.  I'm attempting to use the `firstOrNew` method to achieve this:

```
$store = Store::firstOrNew(array('ext_hash' => $ext_hash, 'ext_type_id' => EXT_TYPE_ID));
```

However, this code is throwing a `MassAssignmentException`.

Is the only way to avoid this exception to assign `fillable` properties on the class level?  According to the documentation, I should be able to assign `fillable` properties on the instance level, rather than for the entire class, but how would I do that?

Here's the code for the `Store` model:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;

class Store extends Eloquent{

        use SoftDeletingTrait;

        public function products(){
                return $this->hasMany('Product');
        }

        public function faqs(){
                return $this->hasMany('ProductFaq');
        }

        public function customer_questions(){
                return $this->hasMany('CustomerQuestion');
        }

        public function users(){
                return $this->hasMany('User');
        }

}
```

Comment: please add the codes of `Store` model to your question.

Comment: I added the code as requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fillable()` is the method you need:

```
$search = array('ext_hash' => $ext_hash, 'ext_type_id' => EXT_TYPE_ID);

$store = (Store::where($search)->first())
  ?: with(new Store)->fillable(array_keys($search))->fill($search);
```

or:

```
$store = new Store;

$store = ($store->where($search)->first()) ?: $store->fillable(array_keys($search))->fill($search);
```

Comment: The `fillable` function will only make the attributes fillable for this operation right?

Comment: To be precise: for the instance `$store`, so this and any following operation on it.

Comment: So, after this operation, whatever we set fillable on Store with this method will be fillable without calling this method again?

Comment: `fillable` is instance property, not static. So it works only for the instance you set in on. It doesn't affect other/new instances of `Store` model.